# Поиск и подсчет одинаковых значений массива (js)

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет! Имеется массив

```js
var arr=["aa","aa","ab","ab","ac","a","s",];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подсчитать одинаковое количество элементов и вывести в массив  в виде array [  aa:3, ab:2 , ac:1, a:1, s:1   ]. В интернете нашел решение в виде

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", ];

var arr2 = [];
for (i in arr) {
  if (arr2[arr[i]] != undefined) {
    (arr2[arr[i]] ++)
  } else {
    (arr2[arr[i]] = 1)
  }
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Но вся сложность в том, что в arr2 значения выводятся не в отдельный элемент массива, а в один. Из-за этого я не могу применить arr.sort() для того, чтобы отсортировать по количеству повторений.  Если кто-то может помочь, буду ооочень рад!

Comment: _[ aa:3, ab:2 , ac:1, a:1, s:1 ]_ - так нельзя в яваскрипте - это ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: А в каком виде тогда можно представить? Просто моя конечная цель-это  отсортировать по количеству повторов. Чтобы самый частый элемент был наверху и т.д. по убыванию.

Comment: а само количество повторов нужно?

Comment: Да. Должно получиться что-то в виде aa-2 ab-2 ac-1 a-1 s-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) может принимать функцию сравнения, в которой как раз и можно сравнивать количество повторений, а не зами элементы.

Кроме того, так как в массив добавляются нечисловые ключи, можно обойтись без второго массива:

```
for (var len = arr.length, i = len; --i >= 0;) {
  if (arr[arr[i]]) {
    arr[arr[i]] += 1;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    arr[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
```

Так как добавленные свойства не числовые, они не участвуют в сортировке, но к ним можно обращаться в функции сравнения:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return arr[b] - arr[a];
});
```

Для вывода можно воспользоваться несколькими путями: например, получить новый массив с элементами в которых будут поля соответствующие и элементу, и количеству его повторений. Либо воспользоваться функцией [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Пример:

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s"];

for (var len = arr.length, i = len; --i >= 0;) {
  if (arr[arr[i]]) {
    arr[arr[i]] += 1;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    arr[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return arr[b] - arr[a];
});

console.log(arr);
var stringResult = JSON.stringify(arr, function(k, v) {
  if (k == '') return v;
  return `${v} - ${arr[v]}`;
}, 2);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = stringResult;
console.log(stringResult);
console.log(arr.map((el, i, a) => ({
  [el]: a[el]
})));
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Чтобы не работать с массивом как с объектами можно воспользоваться функцией [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) и сразу получить массив, который можно будет отсортировать.

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", "s", "s"];

var resultReduce = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (!acc.hash[cur]) {
    acc.hash[cur] = { [cur]: 1 };
    acc.map.set(acc.hash[cur], 1);
    acc.result.push(acc.hash[cur]);
  } else {
    acc.hash[cur][cur] += 1;
    acc.map.set(acc.hash[cur], acc.hash[cur][cur]);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  hash: {},
  map: new Map(),
  result: []
});

var result = resultReduce.result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return resultReduce.map.get(b) - resultReduce.map.get(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `splice` юзать как то подозрительно - у него он в худшем случае сложность `o(n)` уж лучше по памяти немного уйдёт чем тормоза по времени будут )

Comment: @ampawd, чтобы были тормоза, массив должен быть довольно большим. Плюс неизвестно, как именно реализован и оптимизирован splice в конкретном браузере, поэтому про его сложность ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: тогда тоже самое можно и сказать об использовании `Map`

Comment: а вобще [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175925/whats-the-time-complexity-of-array-splice-in-google-chrome) кое что о сложности

Comment: @ampawd, думаешь за пять лет совсем ничего не поменялось? тем более рассмотрен пример одного V8, и даже на нем, показано, чтобы было заметно нужна коллекция с миллионами элементов.

Comment: `Map` со строковыми ключами вырождается в объект, с дополнительными функциями. Поэтому просто нет смысла его использовать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48467/discussion-between-ampawd-and-grundy).

Comment: Работает отлично-считает, сортирует. Не могли бы ещё помочь все это вывести на экран. У меня получается вывести только сами значения массива, без количества повторений... Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: @Александр, в ответе два сниппета - и **оба** выводят и значения и повторения.

Comment: Я имею ввиду не в консоль, а на саму HTML страницу. Я Пытался использовать for (var key in result[zz]) {   
    document.write( key+ " \n")   }   Но в итоге выводится только значения массива, без количества повторений. В Консоль то все выводится как раз замечательно

Comment: @Александр, ну смотри, на консоль выводится строка - ты можешь взять эту строку и добавить в innerHTML нужного элемента, либо в свойство value, если например это textarea

Comment: @Александр, обновил пример

Comment: На сайте, когда жму Выполнить код, выводится на экран. Пробую в браузере выдает ошибку - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)(anonymous function)

Comment: Все, решил проблему. Добавил $(document).ready(function data() { })

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", ];
var arr2 = {};
var arr3 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr2[arr[i]]) {
    arr2[arr[i]] += 1;
  } else {
    arr2[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
console.log(arr2);

var forsort = [];
for (var item in arr2)
  forsort.push([item, arr2[item]])
forsort.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1]
  })
for (var z = 0; z < forsort.length; z++) {
  arr3[forsort[z][0]] = forsort[z][1];
}
console.log(arr3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="arr1"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а теперь можно как-нибудь отсортировать  ключи этого  объекта  по количеству повторов?

Comment: так вы по сути ничего нового не поменяли в решении автора )) да ещё и не отсортировали ничего

Comment: @Александр поправил...

Answer (score 0):

вот вам два решения - второе использует `es6` структуру `Map`, первое довольно банальное.

А для сортировки нужно получить массив, например вот такого вида

`[{arrayItem: aa, count: 2}, {arrayItem: ab, count: 2}, ...]`

чтобы была возможность отсортировать эти элементы по полю `count`, а индексы должны быть целочисленными, у вас они строковые, потому и не отсортировать их.

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", "s", "s"];

function getCountsSorted_1(arr) {
    var counts = [];
    var res = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        if (counts[arr[i]]) {
            (counts[arr[i]]++);
        } else {
            (counts[arr[i]] = 1)
        }
    }

    var j = 0;
    for (var i in counts) {
        res[j++] = {
            arrayItem: i,
            count: counts[i]
        };
    }

    return res.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.count < b.count;
    }).map(function(entry) {
        var ret = {};
        ret[entry.arrayItem] = entry.count;
        return ret;
    });
}

function getCountsSorted_2(arr) {
    var counts = new Map();

    for (var i in arr) {
        if (counts.has(arr[i])) {
            counts.set(arr[i], counts.get(arr[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            counts.set(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }

    return Array.from(counts).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[1] < b[1];
    }).map(function(entry) {
        var ret = {};
        ret[entry[0]] = entry[1];
        return ret;
    });
}


console.log(getCountsSorted_1(arr));
console.log(getCountsSorted_2(arr));
```

Comment: в чем смысл использования `Map`?

Comment: @Grundy удобство

Comment: в данном случае лишние вызовы has, set, get. Используя обычный объект можно обойтись и  без них

Comment: @Grundy ну можно и обычным объектом обойстись - вы бы хотя бы одно своё решение дали бы (если есть) )

Comment: @Grundy смысл в том, чтобы использовать `Array.from` далее, обычный объект в массив он не превратит

Comment: @Grundy вот с обычным объектом сделал, если интересно - https://jsfiddle.net/zfmvb77g/3/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s"],
    counts = {},
    res = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    counts[arr[i]] = (counts[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
Object.keys(counts).sort(function(a, b) {
    return counts[b] - counts[a]
}).forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {
    res.push([el, counts[el]]);
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: у вас сортировуется неправильно - надо по убыванию `res[b] - res[a]`

Comment: не выводится количество повторений

Comment: Спасибо, подправил, с каунтерами немного запутаннее, но структуру результата можно выбрать кому как привычно. Как по мне, то этот вариант все же более читабельный =)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге рабочий код:

```js
var arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", "s", "s"];

var resultReduce = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (!acc.hash[cur]) {
    acc.hash[cur] = { [cur]: 1 };
    acc.map.set(acc.hash[cur], 1);
    acc.result.push(acc.hash[cur]);
  } else {
    acc.hash[cur][cur] += 1;
    acc.map.set(acc.hash[cur], acc.hash[cur][cur]);
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  hash: {},
  map: new Map(),
  result: []
});

var result = resultReduce.result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return resultReduce.map.get(b) - resultReduce.map.get(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

Но теперь надо, чтобы результат выводился в любое место на экран  с указанием количества повторов. У меня получается выводить только сами значений массива, кол-во почему-то не выводится?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["aa", "aa", "ab", "ab", "ac", "a", "s", "s", "s"]
const obj = arr.reduce(
  (acc, rec) => {
    return (typeof acc[rec] !== 'undefined') ? { ...acc,
      [rec]: acc[rec] + 1
    } : { ...acc,
      [rec]: 1
    }
  }, {}
)
const newArr = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => ({
  [key]: obj[key]
}))

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]